# Easiest way to grab this data

Tags: php, oop, screen-scraping, web-scraping

Using Php, how can I grab this data: 
http://www.google.com/search?q=xbox+360&tbm=shop&hl=en&aq=f

in particular on that page I want to grab "**$160**", "**$210**"... etc and store that part in a variable?

I tried using:

```
<?php

    # don't forget the library
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    # this is the global array we fill with article information
    $Prices = array();

    getPrices('http://www.google.com/search?q=xbox+360&tbm=shop&hl=en&aq=f');

function getPrices($page) {
    global $Prices;

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($page);

    $items = $html->find('#leftnav');   

    foreach($items as $post) {
        # remember comments count as nodes
        $Prices[] = $post->children(0)->outertext;
    }
}

?>


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
<?php
    foreach($Prices as $item) {
        echo $item[0];
        #echo $item[1];
    }
?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but that outputs this: `<`

Maybe this was the tougher solution to grab this. Does anyone know of an easier way to pull just that first value, say all on that first page?

Answer (score 2):

Web scraping is quite a grey area really (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues). Google have in place various prevention methods for blocking automatic scrapers. At first they will put up a captcha code to try and stop your tool, if the scraping continues, they can go all out and block your IP.

If you want to get the prices, I suggest you use the Google Search API for Shopping - http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html